# Why doesn't my GenServer handle_cast get called

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am using `GenServer` in my module as below. In the init method, it creates a redis connection to the database. The `put` method will send values to be saved in redisdb. The `handle_cast` method will call the command on redis connection to do the database operation.

```
defmodule RedisClient do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  # Client
  def start(url, pwd, hkey) do
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__, {url, pwd, hkey});
  end

  def init({url, pwd, hkey}) do
    Logger.info("connect to url #{url} #{pwd} #{hkey}");
    case Redix.start_link(url) do
      {:ok, conn} -> case Redix.command(conn, ["auth", pwd]) do
        {:ok, message} -> {:ok, conn, hkey}
        _ -> {:error}
      end
    end
  end

  def put(pid, field, value) do
    Logger.info("put #{field} #{value}")
    GenServer.cast(pid, {:hset, field, value})
  end

  def handle_cast({:hset, field, value}, {conn, hkey}) do
    Logger.info("write to database #{field} #{value}")
    result = Redix.command(conn, ["hset", hkey, field, value]);
    {:noreply, {conn, hkey}}
  end

end
```

Below is the output from `iex` console. The database connection is established but the `handle_cast` is not called when I call `put` method. What is wrong with my implementation?

```
iex(tbc@192-168-1-7)85> {:ok, pid} = RedisClient.start("redis://localhost", "mypassword", "mykey")
{:ok, #PID<0.23038.0>}
iex(tbc@192-168-1-7)86> 
11:19:49.554 [info]  connect to url redis://localhost mypassword mykey
iex(tbc@192-168-1-7)87> RedisClient.put(pid, "field1", "value1")
:ok
iex(tbc@192-168-1-7)88> 
11:20:26.429 [info]  put field1 value1
```

Comment: I think you need to return `{:ok, {conn, hkey}}` from `init/1`.

Comment: Start by using `start_link` - only use `start` if you know what you're doing, by default you want to have linked processes.

I don't get the question completely - your REPL session shows the correct behaviour. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the different between `start_link` and `start`? The problem is `handle_cast` is not called and @Justin_Wood gave the correct answer for that.

Comment: @ZhaoYi `start` will only start the new process. `start_link` will both start the new process and link it to the current one. The link means that the current process will be notified if the new process dies or crashes for any abnormal reason. You can read more [here](http://elixir-lang.github.io/getting-started/processes.html#links).

Comment: @JustinWood Good to know, thanks

Comment: Something completely different: you don't really need a GenServer here, I'd say. You can simply open the Redix connection and do puts and gets directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GenServer` is not actually running. If you were to run the following code, you will get the same result.

```
iex(1)> {:ok, pid} = RedisClient.start(url, pwd, hkey)
iex(2)> Process.alive?(pid)
false
```

The problem is that you are returning a three element tuple from your `GenServer`'s [`init/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:init/1) callback. The third option is supposed to be a timeout. Your `GenServer` is crashing when it starts because the `hkey` is not holding a valid timeout value.

In your case, you will want to return `{:ok, {conn, hkey}}` instead.